# CronJob executing only once

Tags: node.js, cron

I'm using CronJob for NodeJS https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron

I don't understand why but my CronJob is running only once. It is supposed to run once every 10 seconds but after the first run it doesn't restart.

```
async function Job(moneda, condicion) {
console.log('init');
        var res = await Analyzer.GetSpread(moneda);
        var spread = res.MaxExchange.Bid/res.MinExchange.Ask;
        console.log('Spread: ' + spread + 'Moneda: ' + moneda);
        if (await condicion.CumpleCondicion(spread)){
                var ids = await db.GetSuscripciones();
                var mensaje = 'Spread: ' + spread.toFixed(3) + '\nMenor Ask: ' + res.MinExchange.Exchange + '--> ' + res.MinExchange.Ask + '\nMayor Bid: ' + res.MaxExchange.Exchange + '--> ' + res.MaxExchange.Bid;
                for (var i = 0, len = ids.length; i < len; i++) {
                        bot.SendAlert(ids[i].id,mensaje);
                }
        }
console.log('end');  //this is reached
}



exports.Start = function(value){
        condicionBTC = new condicionState('btc');
        new CronJob('*/10 * * * * *', Job('btc',condicionBTC), null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
}
```

And this is printed in the console (only once)

```
init
Spread: 1.007141110114658 Moneda: btc
cumple condicion 1.007141110114658
end
```

If there's some exception stopping the cron job, where should I catch it so I can see what's going on?

I've added this

```
var job = new CronJob('*/10 * * * * *', Job('btc',condicionBTC), null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
setInterval(function(){ console.log(job.running); }, 3000);
```

and keeps printing true

Comment: Cron only allows for a minimum of one minute (See: https://askubuntu.com/a/802).

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron and it allows up to 1 run per second

Comment: can you use onTick: function() {   console.log('job ticked'); } inside job configuration i.e. new CronJob to check if your job is ticking?

Comment: I've added `setInterval(function(){ console.log(job.running); }, 3000);` and it prints true every time

Answer (score 0):

Your cron pattern is wrong. According to https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron :
"this library has six fields, with 1 second as the finest granularity."

- Seconds: 0-59
- Minutes: 0-59
- Hours: 0-23
- Day of Month: 1-31
- Months: 0-11 (Jan-Dec)
- Day of Week: 0-6 (Sun-Sat)

So your cron pattern is trying to run every 10th of a second, which is not possible.

Try replacing your cron pattern with `'10 * * * * *'`

Comment: That would run once every minute, which I don't mean to achieve. This pattern used to work, I'm starting to wonder if the parameters for the function broke CronJob.

Comment: @B. Milford your suggested pattern will execute on 10th second of every minute but op need it to be executed every 10 second so the pattern in the question is right.

Comment: @krish you are correct. I was wrong. Working example here:
https://runkit.com/5a9852edcccf570012d51b2b/5a98531da4606a001219e779